# What is Kronos Corporation?

Tags: marvel

I have very much enjoyed playing *Lego Marvel Avengers*, but one particular location in Manhattan intrigued me. The building in the background of the image with the large letter K in a circle is the Kronos Corporation headquarters. But, what is Kronos Corporation, who is it associated with, and how does it fit into the Marvel universe?

[image: Screenshot from "Lego Marvel Avengers", showing a building with the Kronos Corporation logo: The letter "K" in a flaming circle.]

Comment: @JRE - adding the information in the image description to the main text of the post doesn't add anything that the image itself doesn't already provide, and only serves to duplicate the content for anyone relying on the alt text. The purpose of the alt text is to serve the same purpose to those who can't see the image as the image serves to those who can see the image.

Comment: @Mithical:  The added text was in the alt text.  The information was clearly intended to be of use to all readers.  You've take it out and hidden it again.  Alt-text doesn't show up for every one on every browser.  Whatever.  I found the text informative as I was correcting other gramatical stuff.  You don't find it useful.  Meh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the mainstream 616 Marvel universe, [The Kronas Corporation](http://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kronas_Corporation_(Earth-616)) (later rebranded as The Kronos Corporation, which is the name used in the game) was a massive company headed by [Aleksander Lukin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksander_Lukin), a former Soviet general. He used the corporation to bankroll his secret war on the United States. Lukin sold a cache of special objects originally created by the KGB in order to start Kronas and used the Cosmic Cube's reality-warping powers to buy Roxxon Oil and cement Kronas as a major US company.

It is most prominently seen in *The Winter Soldier* arc of the *Captain America* comic series.

[image: The Kronas building as it appears in the comics]

[Two](http://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kronas_Corporation_(Earth-9021)) [other](http://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kronas_Corporation_(Earth-9230)) alternate reality versions of the company also existed.

Comment: Kron**a**s, surely?

Comment: It is definitely "Kronos" in-game. Perhaps the other versions mentioned have slightly different spellings.

Comment: According to the linked fandom wiki, it was later rebranded as *Kronos* (edited post to reflect this) @Valorum

Comment: ... which (edit) was sadly [rejected](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/why-was-my-edit-rejected) :( @Valorum

Comment: He used the Cosmic Cube to buy a company...because when all you have is a nail, supernatural artifacts with power over the universe start looking like hammers, I guess.

Comment: Slightly surprised it wasn’t run by Krang the Kronqueror.